# Using KNSemiModalViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I want a TableView in my App like the Maps-App in iOS 10. Im not really sure how i should do this. My idea was to use the Pod of  the KNSemiModalViewController (https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNSemiModalViewController).

Take a look at the example show's me that i should only import the Class

```
import KNSemiModalViewController_hons82
```

and write this line's? But how should this code look like in Swift?

```
[self presentSemiViewController:modalVC withOptions:@{
     KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack : @(NO),
     KNSemiModalOptionKeys.parentAlpha : @(0.8)
 }];
```

Or is there a other opportunity to get a view like the iOS 10 Maps-App?

Comment: You can use cocoa pods (https://cocoapods.org/pods/KNSemiModalViewController_hons82)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's really simple.

```
import KNSemiModalViewController_hons82
```

After the Import you just need the following lines of code to open the view called by button click, for example.

```
let modalView = UIStoryboard(name: "SemiModalView", bundle:
    nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SemiModalView")

self.presentSemiViewController(modalView, withOptions:
    [KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack.takeRetainedValue():false, 
     KNSemiModalOptionKeys.parentAlpha.takeRetainedValue():0.5, 
     KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration.takeRetainedValue():0.3])
```

In the called VC you can use

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, (self.view.frame.height * 0.5))
```

in the `viewDidLoad()` Methode to set the size of the SemiModalView. 
You can also add a button or something else to dismiss the SemiModalView with the following line. `self.dismissSemiModalView()`